# Get hash parameters in request URL in spring controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Suppose I have a URL like:

```
../search/?p1=value1&p2=value2#h1=value1&h2=value2
```

In a Spring controller, I can get the values of the parameters p1 and p2, using the controller method below...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView searchSC(HttpServletRequest request, 
     HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam String p1, @RequestParam String p2){  
// my controller code
}
```

What is the best way to get the hashParam values h1 and h2 in the controller?

Answer (score 6):

You can't because fragments should not be, and typically are not, sent to the server. They are a client side concept. They are meaningless to a server as they do not identify a resource, they identify a subcomponent of the resource.